# Criação de novos ambientes (environments) no Anaconda 3

Tags: python, anaconda

Primeiramente peço desculpas se a minha pergunta é muito básica ou se não faz sentido para vocês, ainda estou iniciando a minha caminhada na linguagem Python. Direto ao ponto, minha pergunta é: Porque devemos criar novos ambientes para usar o Anaconda e somente nele instalar os pacotes que iremos usar (pandas, tensorflow, etc.)? Porque não podemos fazer tudo no base (root)? Não seria mais simples?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho feito cursos online que usam o python, a primeira coisa que os instrutores fazem é criar um novo ambiente para trabalhar. Pesquisei aqui no site e no google e não encontrei algo que abordasse especificamente esta questão, o mais próximo foi este artigo: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/why-you-need-python-environments-and-how-to-manage-them-with-conda-85f155f4353c. Lá fala que fazemos isso quando precisamos usar diferentes versões do python. Seria apenas esta a explicação ou teria outro motivo? Posso ter entendido errado, mas para mim isto não fez muito sentido, nos cursos online uso apenas uma versão do python

Comment: Não faço idéia de onde vem tudo isso. Aqui eu simplesmente baixei o Py 3, descompactei numa pastinha (e mais a PyQt) e funciona sem problema. Poderia fazer coisa mais complexa, mas antes de ter motivo é besteira. Vou comparar com linux: mantenho mais de um servidor, alguns são para uso em intranet  alguns expostos na internet, com serviços rodando. Se eu fosse seguir tutoriais ia encher a máquina de coisas desnecessárias como Docker etc (que tem seu uso em casos bem específicos, mas é totalmente supérflo  nos meus cenários e só serviria para consumir recursos à toa) só por causa de "moda".

Comment: Não tou dizendo que em certos cenários mais avançados não seja interessante fazer o que falou, mas se pra iniciar com Py for pra complicar tanto assim, acho que a filosofia da coisa já morreu no ninho.

Comment: Nos cursos da udemy os instrutores sempre criam um ambiente novo pra trabalhar mas eu nunca entendi o porquê disso. Na minha opinião, dá pra fazer tudo no base (root) mesmo, só queria entender se tinha algum motivo por traz disso que eu não estava entendo. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Esse seu ultimo comentário ao menos já explica de onde vem o conceito :D - Cada vez mais penso que certos cursos são aulas de "boas práticas" (se entender realmente o que são as "boas práticas" no nosso ramo, vai saber que não foi um elogio kkk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se sua dúvida for relacionada ao motivo de ter que criar ambientes virtuais para projetos em python (virtualenvs, venv, workon) acho que consigo resumir da seguinte forma:

- No caso do ubuntu, que utiliza o python para renderizar alguns componentes do S.O, não é legal instalar pacotes até por que você pode acabar excluindo pacotes que são essenciais para o funcionamento do mesmo (já fiz isso rs).
- Ao criar um virtualenv você encapsula tudo dentro daquele ambiente (versão do python, libraries)
- Acaba se tornando uma boa prática, até mesmo a IDE do pycharm incentiva ao configurar um projeto a você criar seu virtual environment

Em outro caso, imagine que você tenha um aplicativo totalmente desenvolvido e não queira fazer nenhuma alteração nas bibliotecas que está usando, mas, ao mesmo tempo, comece a desenvolver outro aplicativo que requer as versões atualizadas dessas bibliotecas. O que você vai fazer ? É onde virtualenv entra em jogo. Ele cria ambientes isolados para seu aplicativo python e permite que você instale bibliotecas python nesse ambiente isolado em vez de instalá-las globalmente.

Comment: Era essa mesmo a minha dúvida. Demorou um pouco para me adaptar aos ambientes virtuais mas agora consegui. Muito obrigado!